# Laravel: orderBy find position of user?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page where I list the richest users on my game.

```
$topCredits = User::orderBy('credits', 'DESC')->limit($limit)->get();
```

the limit is currently set to 5 and sometimes doesn't show a user if they aren't that rich. I need a way of still showing the user their position (IE: 1st, 2nd, 9th, 24th) but also showing the top 5. I was wondering is there a way I can do this without an extra query, or how would I do it with an extra query? Finding a certain user in a list of `User` models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I had to do something similar. I just create an iterator 
`@foreach ($users as $index => $user)` so then to know the position you’ll only `{{ $index+1 }}`

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel [take](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-take) helper

```
$credits = User::orderBy('credits', 'DESC')->get();

$topFiveCredits =  $credits->take(5);
```